# Ruby Docker image does not communiate with Vault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, hashicorp-vault

I have a ruby application running in a docker image.
I am running this image on my Ubuntu dev environment.

Ubuntu env has Vault configured and runs fine (in dev mode and logs posted below).

I exposed the VAULT_ADDR and VAULT_TOKEN to the docker image but my application throws exception on the vault instance.

Code in ruby:

```
#Check if OTP key already exists for given uid
  def exist?(uid)
    Vault.logical.read("totp/keys/#{uid}").present? // Exception is here

Exception: no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

I configured the vault like this,

```
vault server -dev
vault login 50921e0b-d79b-a5d1-1b86-ef986c4844c4
vault secrets enable totp
```

Exported both VAULT_ADDR and VAULT_TOKEN so my docker image can access them.

```
export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'
export VAULT_TOKEN='50921e0b-d79b-a5d1-1b86-ef986c4844c4'
```

VAULT LOGS:

==> Vault server configuration:

```
                 Cgo: disabled
     Cluster Address: https://127.0.0.1:8201
          Listener 1: tcp (addr: "127.0.0.1:8200", cluster address: "127.0.0.1:8201", tls: "disabled")
           Log Level: info
               Mlock: supported: true, enabled: false
    Redirect Address: http://127.0.0.1:8200
             Storage: inmem
             Version: Vault v0.9.5
         Version Sha: 36edb4d42380d89a897e7f633046423240b710d9

WARNING! dev mode is enabled! In this mode, Vault runs entirely in-memory
and starts unsealed with a single unseal key. The root token is already
authenticated to the CLI, so you can immediately begin using Vault.

You may need to set the following environment variable:

$ export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'

The unseal key and root token are displayed below in case you want to
seal/unseal the Vault or re-authenticate.

Unseal Key: 0o+LdZPhvQBEjVZtUlX5UPac9dcXBLqpU1i1jqBw/2s=
Root Token: 50921e0b-d79b-a5d1-1b86-ef986c4844c4

Development mode should NOT be used in production installations!
```

Comment: Same problem here. Were you able to find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the generic secret back end using command.

`vault secrets disable secret`

My guess is your ruby app is trying to connect to the default secrets back end i.e **secret**, the same happen in my java app, after disabling the generic back end I could able to read from my custom secrets path.